# Rotate SVG and keep children elements in their places

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I need to rotate the wheel and keep the icons stable in their places (see the attached images) [image] [image]

Below is some code that I wrote, but it works not as expected.
I use SnapSVG plugin (but it does not matter).

```
const pie = Snap('#pie-svg');
const pies = pie.selectAll('.pie');
const icons = pie.selectAll('.icon');

const ROTATIONS = {
    'pie-1': 180,
    'pie-2': 120,
    'pie-3': 60,
    'pie-4': 0,
    'pie-5': -60,
    'pie-6': -120,
};

function pieClickHandler(e) {
    const id = this.attr('id');
    // const pieCoords = pie.getBBox();

    pie.animate({
       transform: `r${ROTATIONS[id]},0,0`
    }, 3000, mina.easeout);

    icons.forEach((icon) => {
        const iconCoords = icon.getBBox();

        icon.animate({
            transform: `r${-1 * ROTATIONS[id]},${iconCoords.cx},${iconCoords.cy}`
        }, 3000, mina.easeout);
    });
}

pies.forEach(function (pie) {
    pie.click(pieClickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example including your SVG (on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example).

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is to actually not have the icons be a child of the wheel, but instead, have both the wheel and the div containing the icons be absolute positioned children inside a another div. This way, they are siblings that can overlap each-other, and the rotation of the wheel doesn't affect the icons.

```
<div id="wheel-container">
    <div id="wheel"></div>
    <div id="icon-container">
        <div class="icons" id="icon1"></div>
        <div class="icons" id="icon2"></div>
        <div class="icons" id="icon3"></div>
        <div class="icons" id="icon4"></div>
        <div class="icons" id="icon5"></div>
        <div class="icons" id="icon6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the icons to be rotated with the wheel, but keep staying horizontally aligned

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this, is to create a hidden tiny point for each icon. Add it to the group/wheel that is rotated.

Then when you rotate it, grab the position of the point, and move the icon to that point.

So we set up our wheel and icon and hidden point...

```
var c = s.circle(300,300,150).attr({ fill: 'yellow' });
var icon1Position = s.rect(0,0,2,2).transform('t400,350');
var g = s.group();
g.append(icon1Position,c)

var icon1 = s.rect(0,0,iconWidth,iconHeight).attr({ fill: 'red' });
```

And then we animate. We use the function version of Snap animate, that calls a func during every animation step.

We rotate the wheel. Then we get a breakdown of where the tiny rect is, using globalMatrix. Then we transform the icons center to that position (so adjust by half the width/center).

```
Snap.animate(0,180, function( val ) { 

  g.attr({ transform: 'r' + val + ',300,300' });
  var newLoc = icon1Position.transform().globalMatrix.split(); 
  icon1.transform( 't' + (newLoc.dx-iconWidth/2) + ',' + (newLoc.dy-iconHeight/2) );

}, 2000 );
```

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wd1dbats/36/) would just need extending to an array or whatever you want, to work for multiple icons.

The other way would be to inversely rotate each icon, relative to the wheels rotation, but that feels slightly clunkier, and may not always be quite exact in terms of being 100% orientated correct.